# How did the "Rails can't Scale" meme start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, history

One meme about Rails is that [Rails can't Scale](http://canrailsscale.com/). Is it known how this meme started? Was there a particular blog post that argued this is the case?

Comment: If you can answer the question "how [did] this meme start?" then it's not really a meme :-)

Answer (score 11):

I would say that there are real technical issues behind it. The Ruby implementation (at least ruby 1.8) is not designed for concurrency :  ruby 1.8 has a [global interpretor lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock), and it uses [green threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads) instead of OS native threads.

So, for a web application to scale, you have to run multiple ruby interpretors, and make them work together.

Note : I am not into web development, and It's been a long time I haven't used ruby. Maybe ruby 1.9 or JRuby don't have these issues. Maybe the global lock is not a real problem for scaling up.

Comment: JRuby doesn't have the same problem, but Ruby 1.9 does.

Answer (score 9):

Well, to scale, you need reasonable performance per line of code, right? I'm not talking C++ levels, but ... check out

http://dada.perl.it/shootout/index.html

for example on heapsort

[image]

But hey, Ruby *is* faster than vbscript!

Comment: For those wondering, Red = CPU, Green = Memory.

Comment: note this is an old benchmark for SURE, but you asked about history, and this is probably why.

Comment: I'm not a hard-core Rubyist but I bet I can think of the come-back: You can do much more with a single line of Ruby than you can with a single line of C++. Seriously, why is "line of code" a good base unit?

Comment: Your mixing up scalability with performance; scalability is ability to increase the performance by throwing hardware at the problem.

Comment: My question is, what the heck is up with vpascal?

Comment: That's Ruby *1.6.7*, which is more than a little outdated.

Answer (score 7):

I think it was because Twitter was driven by Ruby on Rails and around mars-may 2008 they had some significant downtimes which  started the meme

Comment: They had to switch to scala because of that, too.

Comment: @Mahmoud Hossam didn't they only swap out performance critical parts to scala and leave the rest as Rails?

Comment: @mathepic I think the UI parts are still written in Rails, check their github for more details.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, there were several "hot" ror startups that suffered issues scaling. I believe that's where the issue primarily came from.

However, there's been performance issues with ruby/ror in the history prior to those meltdowns.

**See: Ruby interpreter leaking memory on long running processes:**

http://groups.google.com/group/god-rb/browse_thread/thread/01cca2b7c4a581c2

http://engineering.twitter.com/2011/03/building-faster-ruby-garbage-collector.html

**DHH's "rails myths" which documents 400 restarts per day:**

http://www.loudthinking.com/posts/31-myth-2-rails-is-expected-to-crash-400-timesday

And of course the infamous *rails is a ghetto* rant from Zed Shaw.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that Rails is based around the Active Record pattern, which is quick and easy to get started with, but can slide into a constant refactoring battle as your app's complexity increases.  I think that's why you hear about startups in particular having troubles: they're able to get something working quickly, but as they add features, the complexity grows and that's when the trouble starts.

Comment: Speaking from experience creating a Rails application, I will second this.  Not just in scaling but Rails in general runs into issues when you need to do more than just reading/writing a single record from a database.  If you need some kind of complex business logic, for instance, Rails can hinder you more than it benefits you.  It's still a superb framework and a beautiful language, but it's not perfect (not that anything is "perfect" in programming).